# Object oriented aiohttp server

Tags: python, aiohttp

I'm hoping to create an asynchronous web server to handle a large volume of requests. A friend recommended I use aiohttp to achieve this. I am keen to encapsulate as much as possible into a server object - is this possible? How can I achieve this?

I'm working with Python 3.6 - I have been unable to find a similar example in the docs.

I would like to achieve something similar to this:

```
from aiohttp import web


class Server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = web.Application()
        self.app.add_routes(web.RouteTableDef())

    @routes.get('/')
    async def hello(request):
        return web.Response(text="Hello, world")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = Server()
```

Just to clarify, the error I am receiving is:

```
NameError: name 'routes' is not defined
```

**Is there a standard way of achieving this type of encapsulation?**

Thanks

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @yorodm Apologies if it's not clear - but the above code does not work - and I'm not aware if there is a standard way to achieve something similar

Comment: What error are you getting or what about it is not working?

Comment: @Jaba NameError: name 'routes' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You should import it first:

```
from aiohttp import web
routes = web.RouteTableDef()
# your code...
```